# AWS resize volume of instance gives UnauthorizedOperation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-cli

I started an AWS instance of an Ubuntu 18.04 Server via the CLI from my Linux machine.
That worked. However, I wanted to increase the size of the volume from the standard of 8gb to 100gb with the command

`aws ec2 modify-volume --volume-id "vol-XXXXXXXX" --size 100`

However, this returns an "UnauthorizedOperation"-error.

I already tried to do it manually via the console, but there it didn't work as well. But I could create a new volume of size 100 gb. I have enough credits, since I'm using the Education Starter Account with 100 credits left.

I also checked my SecurityGroup, but the only rules I applied where for network protocols.

Why am I not authorized and how do I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple and disappointing. Vocareum limits possible operations, also, you don't have root access. Therefore, some operations are restricted and not executable.

Answer (score 0):

The "UnauthorizedOperation" error indicates that permissions attached to the IAM role or user trying to perform the operation does not have the required permissions.

You can gain more detail by decoding error message from CLI.
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html